# Rails `image_path` not working in css file

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following line in my css file:

```
background-image: url(<%= image_path 'background.jpg' %>);
```

And it yields the following error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...und-image: url(": expected ")", was "<%= image_path ..."
```

I have also tried `asset_path`, but it has the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [The asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass), You can see that using `image-url("background.jpg")` becomes `url(/assets/background.jpg)`, which is what you want if you image is in your `/app/assets/images` directory

So use

```
background-image: image-url("background.jpg")
```

Comment: `image-url` doesn't do anything in CSS if I'm not mistaken. I don't quite understand what you're suggesting. I need a rails function that will return the url.

Comment: Oh I see, its a scss function. Thank you.

Comment: Yes sorry, I tested it in a CSS file and it worked, but realized I'm importing all my CSS files into a SASS file (duh).